# Can an Oracle index be created in a low priority thread/process?

Tags: performance, oracle, indexing

We're all working on the same development database at the same time. Usually this is not a problem, but sometimes we need to create a new index on one of the huge tables. This slows down the database for everyone.

Is there a way to create an index in a low-priority Oracle process, such that the other developers can continue working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create index ... online ?

I think that is exactly what the ONLINE keyword is supposed to do. There may be some impact, but you should be able to continue working with the table.

Comment: Hmm, that seems to take care of the locking. There is still a bit of performance impact. But still a good hint.

Answer (score 2):

You can:

- use the resource manager to create a resource plan that will limit the throughput of the process
- use `nice` or `ionice` on the process to reduce its priority at the OS level
- if you use the enterprise edition then you can create the index `online`